# Postgres query is not executed on Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, postgresql

I've got into an issue. Postgres code(query) is not executed at all. I have to mention that the connection with the DB is correctly done.

I've tried to debug the code but I don't really know what's the problem

````
'use strict';

const config = require('../config');
const emailService = require('./email-service');
const pg = require('pg');
pg.defaults.ssl = true;


 module.exports = function(phone_number, user_name, previous_job, years_of_experience, job_vacancy){
    console.log('sending email');
    let emailContent = 'A new job inquiry from ' + user_name + ' for the job: ' + job_vacancy +
        '.<br> Previous job position: ' + previous_job + '.' +
        '.<br> Years of experience: ' + years_of_experience + '.' +
        '.<br> Phone number: ' + phone_number + '.';

    emailService.sendEmail('New job application', emailContent);
    try{
    var pool = new pg.Pool(config.PG_CONFIG);
    pool.connect(function(err, client, done) {
        if (err) {
            return console.error('Error acquiring client', err.stack);
        }
        client
            .query(
                'INSERT into job_applications ' +
                '(phone_number, user_name, previous_job, years_of_experience, job_vacancy) ' +
                'VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING id',
                [phone_number, user_name, previous_job, years_of_experience, job_vacancy],
                function(err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        console.log('row inserted with id: ' + result.rows[0].id);
                    }

                });
    });
}
catch(e){
    console.log(e, 'error[][][]')
}
    pool.end();
} ```
````

Comment: So you mean if you set a breakpoint at ` client.query` or inside  `function(err, result)` it won't work?

Comment: exactly, it jumps over that code , it seems that postgres code is ignored or something like this

Comment: Are there any logs printed out?

Comment: How about breakpoint placed at the start of `function(err, result)` as @Anatoly mentions? Is it possible that it just fails on `result.rows[0].id` silently, i.e. it actually runs, but doesn't log anything because an error is thrown and swallowed?

Comment: You call `pg.end` than close all active connections before callback is executed. Call it at the end of `function(err, result)` or sometime later when you will no longer need this connection pool.

Comment: It does not log anything ..
The code stops on function(err, result) if I put a breakpoint there but it jumps over the remaining code .

Comment: @Anatoly , I already tried to call pg.end sometime later or even delete it, but I still have the same issue

Comment: @MarcelGrama try to wrap the contents of the `function(err, result)` with another `try...catch` and `console.error` in the `catch`

Comment: @FrantišekŽiačik , I tried and it seems that the error is uncatchable :)) . 
I have to mention that I also tried to do a simpy quey like SELECT * from users and it is not executed...

Comment: So you never go to `pool.connect`'s callback?

Comment: that's correct @Anatoly

Comment: Maybe you somehow out of available connection in this pool? Or it cannot connect and wait for timeout? Can you try a promise version of `pool.connect`?